# Dropping a table having dependencies in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables in postgres database, T1 and T2. One of the columns of T2 is dependent on T1's column by ForeignKey constraint. I want to drop T1. However, I get an error.
`sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.DependentObjectsStillExist) cannot drop table schema_name.T1 because other objects depend on it`

I understand that T2 depends on T1, so T1 cannot be dropped directly. So, either T2 shall also be dropped or the dependent column in T2 should be dropped. However, I am unable to find out how to achieve any of this using sqlalchemy.

I use `table_object.drop(checkfirst = True)` to drop the table. However, the documentation does not give any way to include dropping dependencies as well.

So what is the way to drop dependencies of a table along with the table, using drop method.

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.4

Comment: SQLAlchemy doesn't provide tools for this kind of schema management.  For schema migrations Alembic is the recommended tool.  For one-off changes you could execute the `DROP COLUMN` statement as raw SQL before dropping the table.